# What do I have to do to test my iPhone / iPod App on my iPod Touch (not iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I'm developing an App for my iPod Touch that doesn't use the iPhone-Special-Hardware like phone or cam. I want to test it on my iPod touch. I am already a registered developer (free account, no fee). What are the steps to get my app working on my iPod touch?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay the $99 fee in order to test on any device (iPhone or iPod Touch).

Comment: I'm curious - why do you think so?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay the $99 developer fee, and become an iPhone developer. This will let you install your application on the iPhone or the iPod. You can also do this for free if you jail break you iPod touch, or iPhone.